# How to determine click event for userdefine control array

Tags: c#

I have created an `Array` of `UserControls` which have 1 `PictureBox` and 1 `Button`. Now I want to know which `Button` is pressed from the `Array` of `UserControl`.

```
UserControl u=new UserControl[20];

for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) 
{
    u[j] = new UserControl();               
    u[j].BringToFront();
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(u[j]);
    u[j].Visible = true;
    u[j].button1.Click+=new EventHandler(sad);
}

private void sad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //how to determine which button from the array of usercontrol is pressed?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sender` parameter contains the `Control` instance that generated the event.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
private void sad(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var buttonIndex = Array.IndexOf(u, sender);
}
```

Comment: Error:No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 0):

This should do close to what you want. I can modify as needed to suit your case.

```
FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1 = new FlowLayoutPanel();
void LoadControls()
{
    UserControl[] u= new UserControl[20];
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) 
    {
        u[j] = new UserControl();               
        u[j].BringToFront();
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(u[j]);
        u[j].Visible = true;
        u[j].button1.Click +=new EventHandler(sad);
    }
}

private void sad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Control c = (Control)sender;
    //returns the parent Control of the sender button
    //Could be useful 
    UserControl parent = (UserControl)c.Parent;  //Cast to appropriate type

    //Check if is a button
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        if (c.Name == <nameofSomeControl>) // Returns name of control if needed for checking
        {
            //Do Something
        }

    }
    //Check if is a Picturebox
    else if (c.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
    {

    }
    //etc. etc. etc      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets you what you want:

```
    if (sender is UserControl)
    {
        UserControl u = sender as UserControl();

        Control buttonControl = u.Controls["The Button Name"];
        Button button = buttonControl as Button;
    }
```